# Why EOS can build much faster TPS network on much slower Ethereum network?

Tags: go-ethereum

The TPS of `Ethereum` network is about 15/tps and `EOS` claims that it can achieve millions of TPS through parallel threading and other technology. My understanding is that every `EOS` transaction will be eventually saved to `Ethereum` network as `Ethereum` block. If `Ethereum` can only handles 15TPS, how come EOS can make it into millions of TPS? With thousands of concurrent parallel threads? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: They're moving to their own network using a more centralised consensus engine. The high throughput you mention won't be on the Ethereum network.

Comment: `Richard Horrocks`, I know EOS uses a type of POS consensus algorithm which is much faster than POW. But unless EOS batch process its transactions on Ethereum main chain, I did not see/understand how EOS can be that faster.

Comment: The main point is that it won't be using the Ethereum main chain, it will be using its own chain.

Answer (score 1):

Though the EOS erc20 token lives on the Ethereum network, EOS will launch their own, separate blockchain.  After that point, I don't believe any interaction between the two chains has been planned.

The EOS erc20 was/is purely for fund raising purposes